Interacting with execTransaction on sepolia scan
I have already created a safe contract with 3 owners and 2 confirmations on sepolia. I am trying to interact with execTransaction.
The first thing I do is owner 1 and 2 sign a message off chain, then I serialize the two signatures using your function "buildSignatureBytes" then I go to sepolia scan and fill in the following inputs:
payableAmount: 0.0001,
to: 0xaD740302DFA07A37C52B1Ae1747551eE90Ec74ba,
value: 100
data: "0x"
operation: 0,
safeTxGas: 0
baseGas: 0
gasPrice: 0
gasToken: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
refundReceiver: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
signatures: "0x4deae193b415cd195bc2d8ea6d34f4dc97e6bad27357fcbd1cafd96565187fff4455d5282f7e3d0bf6f4b17893805a450af591f88ee1232cdfbdeb68fe5be22e1be212bc6a579ceb5e2fc313706a168819b7a8d101802c689bc99829c1ccef10e80ac07132490b153669cb103c6a82dfb028a6834399d08aef4f7986096ba29c8f1c"
But it does not run on sepolia scan.
Please can you help me

Are you trying to interact with your safe proxy contract? If yes what version/address are you using? This would be useful to help debug the situation. You can also try using tenderly to simulate the transaction and get more detailed error logs. Please let me know! Thanks in advance  Louis

First I was trying to interact directly with the smart contracts using the proxy and the version it shows me is "1.3.0" obtained running the following command: "await contrato.methods.VERSION().call()"
Then I was trying to follow the github "safe-global/safe-core-sdk" and the propose-transaction and confirm-transaction run very well but execute-transaction fails, but I go to sepolia scan and there I run the "execTransaction" and everything results ok.

Hey Anselmo, is your question answered then?
